# Изменение каждой нечётной строки теста на странице

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Добрый день , подскажите как в тексте на странице в теге `<p>` можно осуществить поиск конца строки, чтобы была возможность менять каждую нечётную строку текста.
То есть

```
<p>Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст 
*Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст* 
Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст
*Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст*</p>
```

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, есть ли в тексте символ переноса строки, или необходимо узнавать конец строки уже после того, как он будет отображен на странице (с учетом ширины <p>)?

Comment: Символов нет, текст как есть. Интересует как именно узнать уже после того как текст будет отображен на странице, учитывая то что ширина строк текста может меняться. Возможно это схоже с  определением переноса слов.

Comment: К сожалению, никогда этим вопросом не занимался. Пока кто-то более знающий ответит точно, могу предложить свои догадки - я бы попробовал вставлять какой-то элемент после каждого слова и проверять его позицию по высоте (быстрый поиск подсказал мне использовать getBoundingClientRect()) либо вставлять текст по слову, проверяя высоту <p> (может очень сильно сказаться на производительности). Единственное, в чем я не уверен - обновляются ли размеры и позиции элементов сразу после их перемещения (и, как следствие, можно ли сделать все в обычном цикле). (Элемент я бы вставлял с нулевой шириной)

Answer (score 5):

Элементарно - берём содержимое `p` (`innerHTML`), разделяем содержимое по переносу строки (`split("\n")`), проходим по массиву (`map`), если индекс чётный (делится на 2 без остатка) - пропускаем, иначе строка нечётная и мы может поменять её. Дальше склеиваем изменённый массив опять по переносу строки (`join`) и вставляем контент в `p`:

```js
let p = document.querySelector('p'),
    data = {
      1: ['Merry', 'christmas'],
      3: ['And happy', 'new year']
    };

p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.split(`\n`).map((e, i) => i % 2 !== 0 ? `${data[i][0]} | ${e} | ${data[i][1]}` : e).join(`\n`);
```

```html
<pre>
<p>Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст 
*Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст* 
Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст
*Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст Текст*</p>
</pre>
```

Comment: Но это получается, что только если мы сами добавляем перенос в текст можно найти `\n`, если у нас изначально сплошной текст без переносов, это не работает. Может вы сможете подсказать , как браузер осуществляет перенос строки или где об этом можно узнать поподробнее.

Comment: @Aivengo, браузер решает когда куда перенести по правилам в CSS, по разметке, иногда даже по положению Луны. Узнать это если и можно, то только великим колдунством уровня Мерлина. Если Вам нужно это колдунство, значит Вы решаете проблему не теми средствами (проблема шурупа молотком).

Answer (score 4):

Почему бы нет.

***Пример:***

```js
$(".stripe").each(function(){
  var obj = $(this);
  var html = obj.html().replace(/(\S+\s*)/g, "<span>$1</span>");
  obj.html(html);
});

function highlight(){
    var offset = 0;
    var colorIndex = 0;
    var colors = ["#ccc","#000"];
    var spans = $(".stripe span");
    
    for(var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++){
        var newOffset = spans[i].offsetTop;  
        
        if(newOffset !== offset){
            colorIndex = colorIndex === 0 ? 1 : 0;
            offset = newOffset;
       }
        
       spans[i].style.color = colors[colorIndex];
    }
}

highlight();
$(window).on("resize", highlight);
```

```css
body {
    font: 13px/1.5 sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stripe">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam dui diam, euismod et pretium at, lacinia condimentum leo. Aenean interdum mi nec metus elementum vel aliquet lorem porttitor. Morbi facilisis sollicitudin libero, id tincidunt lectus convallis faucibus. Curabitur bibendum massa vel tortor rutrum dictum. Donec sit amet sapien eros. Fusce nisi est, vulputate eu pulvinar sed, facilisis a massa. Suspendisse vitae nibh non ante facilisis tristique.

Nunc laoreet, orci eu consectetur bibendum, neque purus auctor justo, nec placerat metus massa in risus. Morbi gravida ultrices nisi, nec faucibus nulla tincidunt eu. Quisque tristique quam non dui sollicitudin blandit tincidunt ante vehicula. Donec massa justo, mollis ut ultricies et, eleifend non nisi. Nullam fermentum interdum ipsum eu elementum. Phasellus vel dui eget ante vehicula adipiscing vel a mauris. Curabitur vitae ipsum sed magna ultrices scelerisque. Ut orci diam, scelerisque pellentesque dapibus vitae, vestibulum nec quam. Maecenas vestibulum vulputate adipiscing.

Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nunc molestie aliquet vehicula. Aliquam porttitor vestibulum felis vitae consectetur. Etiam ac urna at felis lobortis tristique. Maecenas nibh elit, elementum et dictum id, viverra non lectus. Donec hendrerit gravida libero. Duis quis nisi et risus tristique bibendum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Ut accumsan semper magna vel iaculis. Phasellus sagittis tristique orci non placerat. Vivamus felis nibh, semper eu placerat sed, hendrerit vitae odio. Praesent fermentum congue fringilla. Aliquam dolor mauris, tempor eu luctus ac, feugiat ac nibh. Sed non orci lorem.

Quisque ut odio nunc. Duis vel felis nulla. Aliquam rutrum lorem in libero facilisis tristique in vitae dolor. Ut odio eros, suscipit nec egestas eu, gravida suscipit lectus. Suspendisse sed urna quam. Fusce quis sagittis tellus. Cras eleifend euismod ultrices. Fusce egestas orci eu erat hendrerit at eleifend dolor ullamcorper.

Donec a mauris mi. In posuere rutrum tristique. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam ante mi, mattis at facilisis cursus, porta id augue. Morbi feugiat, odio eget imperdiet facilisis, ligula tellus eleifend magna, sagittis imperdiet mi neque vitae erat. Pellentesque condimentum convallis ligula, a sollicitudin neque porttitor vel. Mauris adipiscing pharetra justo, ac molestie ante congue vitae. Vestibulum a est arcu, in laoreet justo. Cras tincidunt eros id ipsum vulputate eu pulvinar odio fermentum.
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно сделать в js. Алгоритм:

- Предварительно каждое слово оборачиваем в `span`
- Проходим в цикле по всем `span` и окрашиваем в один цвет
- До тех пор, пока очередной `span` не начинает располагаться ниже предыдущего
- Его и все последующие окрашиваем в другой цвет
- До тех пор, пока очередной `span` не начинает располагаться еще ниже
- Скрипт запускаем при ресайзе окна, с небольшой задержкой для производительности

Рабочий пример: http://jsfiddle.net/gambala/j0Lbu7ow/

Ответ составил по аналогичному на иностранном Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830449/how-to-target-alternate-odd-even-text-lines